# dropdown not showing items

Tags: c#, asp.net

getting data in `dataset` , but `items` is not visible in `dropdownlist`

**aspx**

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlchgstatus1" runat="server" />
```

**aspx.cs**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShoppingConnectionString"].ConnectionString);    
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_status", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
ddlchgstatus1.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlchgstatus1.DataValueField = "StausID";
ddlchgstatus1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't assigned the [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ddlchgstatus1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ddlchgstatus1.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlchgstatus1.DataValueField = "StausID";
ddlchgstatus1.DataBind();
```